# Chrome for Android: How to enable mobile-friendly ' on web page

Tags: php, android, css, viewpoint

I created this http://nl4.christianity24.org/ using PHP and mysqli, with CSS 3. I got website mobile friendly with Android opera but can't get it friendly on Android Chrome and Firefox. What am I suppose to do.

Like use @media(); what is the best CSS 3 format for mobile view point?

Answer (score 0):

To ensure proper rendering and touch zooming for all devices try adding this meta tag in the `<head>` of your document.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

Then you can customize your website using various media queries like this.

```
// Large devices (desktops, less than 1200px)
@media (max-width: 1199.98px) {
    body {
        background-color: red;
    }
}

// Medium devices (tablets, less than 992px)
@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
    body {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
}

// Small devices (landscape phones, less than 768px)
@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
    body {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}

// Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
    body {
        background-color: violet;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: You have done great... let me test and feedback you. Thanks